Issues writing to the dataverse from power pages when using google authentication
I have a power pages website, and I am trying to write to the dataverse. I am manually coding in VS Code, and not embedding a form using the designer. As the user signs in using their google auth, I am getting a google auth error when trying to write to the entity.
I have tried updating the CORS setting for the site, which is what the console is telling me the issue is. I have also using the safeAjax method. I have also ensured the settings of the specific table have write capabilities for authenticated users.
I need for a user to be able to create a record, or update a record they have previously created. They will need to be authenticated and logged in.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
